# how to fetch a number of rows...from table in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

i have one table name as p_customer now i want to fetch the number of entries from the table and print that number of customers

```
<?php     
 $wherecat3 = "p_customer_status = 'active' AND `p_customer_id` = '".$catRes['p_customer_id']."' ";
 $catsql3 = $general->GetRows('*' ,' p_customer' ,$wherecat3);         
 $catRes3 = mysql_fetch_row($catsql3);

?>


<p><?=$catRes3;?></p>
```

Comment: try [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) function in manual

Comment: Where is `GetRows` defined? What does it do?

Comment: What is happening when you run this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mysqli_num_rows()` to get number of records featched from Mysql result.

```
<?php
$wherecat3 = "p_customer_status = 'active' AND `p_customer_id` = '" . $catRes['p_customer_id'] . "' LIMIT $n";
$catsql3 = $general->GetRows('*', ' p_customer', $wherecat3);
$n = mysqli_num_rows($catsql3);
$catRes3 = mysql_fetch_row($catsql3);
?>
<p><?= $catRes3; ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$catRes3 = mysqli_num_rows($catsql3);
```